# Linearly connecting random points in a canvas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is JS code to show random points on a canvas:

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("showCanvas");
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
randomPoints(myContext, 4);

function randomPoints(canvas, count) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    var r = 5;
    canvas.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    canvas.closePath();
    canvas.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="showCanvas" width="600%" height="400%" style="border:2px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element
</canvas>
```

It works fine, but can't find a way to connect these points in a linear format, e.g. a to d and not a to b, a to c and a to d like it shows below. I need help!

```js
$('.drawLines').click(function() {
  myContext.beginPath();
  // wish there was something I could do here if necessary...
  myContext.stroke();
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by a "linear format"? Do you just want to draw lines between points? If so, have you tried [`ctx.lineTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo)?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, ggorlen. The problem with that method is one needs to hard-code points in it. Meaning I would need to know where x and y is on the canvas and then parse them. Now when you look at my example, I do not have a way of knowing where x and y is and where are they going to be plotted next on the canvas... So, I don't know how to use ctx.lineTo() and ctx.moveTo() methods unless if anyone shows me how I can apply them in my code then I'll be grateful. But to answer your question, yes, I would like to draw a straight line moving across four points after plotting them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You might keep track of the `x` and `y` positions in an array and loop over them, or keep track of the last `x` and `y` and draw the lines on the spot.